# More Waiting in request in python(pymssql)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, api, pymssql

i use request  from pymssql and in a loop i use  this code :

this code is working in loop . but sometimes not working  in this line and waiting or stop in this line without any error and however much i will wait program freez and i must stop and start this code for working ...

```
   schedule.every(30).seconds.do(Quantity)
```

and function Quantity is :

```
def Quantity():
    z = "Token"
    sql1 = "exec dbo.Quantity"
    dt = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
    cursor3 = conn.cursor()
    cursor3.execute(sql1)
    conn.commit()
    sublist=[]
    sqltest = 'select distinct storeid from Quantity'
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute(sqltest)

    result = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    for x in result:
        sublist.extend(x)

    #print(sublist)
    if sublist:
        for y in sublist:
       
        sql3=f"select * from Quantity where storeid = {y}"
            cursor4 = conn.cursor()

            cursor4.execute(sql3)
            result2 = cursor4.fetchall()
            insertObject = []
            columnNames = [column[0] for column in cursor4.description]
            NewColumn=columnNames[1:]
            for record in result2:
                insertObject.append(dict(zip(columnNames, record)))
            storeid = y
            #print(insertObject)
            #print(storeid)
            data2 = json.dumps({
                "storeCode": y,
                "products": insertObject
            }
            )
            try :
                print('quantity')
            except :
                print('No Data Quantity')
            headers = {
                'Authorization': z,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            response2 = requests.request("POST", url2, headers=headers, data=data2, timeout=30)
            uz=response2.status_code
            print(str(uz) +' ' +dt)
            if u == 200:
        print('Success '+ dt)
    else :
        print('No_Data_For_Quantity '+ dt)
```

Comment: The formatting of your post is severely poor. Please fix it. You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do so.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.